# On click of esc button sweet alert should not be closed

Tags: javascript, php

when user clicks on esc alert should not be closed he should click on pay now button to move further.

```
 if($unpaid==true){
     echo $print = '<script>
      function alertOn(){
swal({ 
        title: "No Membership Fees Received",
        text: "Please pay membership fees as per your selected package",
        type: "warning",
        confirmButtonText: "PAY NOW"

      },
      function(){
        window.location.href = "unpaid.php";
    });
};
window.onload = alertOn
</script>';
```

Comment: is there anyone with solution

Answer (score 9):

Yes, you can configure the `swal` function by modifying `allowEscapeKey` and `allowOutsideClick` properties to `false` like:

```
swal({
       title: 'title',
       text: 'your text',
       showConfirmButton: true,
       allowEscapeKey : false,
       allowOutsideClick: false
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

```php
if ($unpaid == true) {
    echo $print1 = '<script>
    function alertOn(){
        swal({ 
            title: "No Membership Fees Received",
            text: "Please pay membership fees as per your selected package",
            type: "warning",
            confirmButtonText: "PAY NOW",
            **allowEscapeKey:false**

          },
          function(){
            window.location.href = "unpaid.php";
        });
    };
    window.onload = alertOn;
</script>';
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I think for this version you can use this:

```
swal({
  title: 'title',
  text: 'your text',
  button: false,
  closeOnClickOutside: false,
  closeOnEsc: false
});
```